# A problem about prime subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

This is a problem from GTM 167 *Field and Galois Theory*.

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. The prime subring of $R$ is the intersection of all subrings of $R$. Show that this intersection is a subring of $R$ that is contained inside all subrings of $R$. Moreover, show that the prime subring of $R$ is equal to $\{n\cdot1:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, where $1$ is the multiplicative identity of $R$.

The first part of this problem is easy.What puzzled me is the second part. I think under this definition, the prime subring of $R$ should be $0$. Even if we only consider the intersection of non-zero subring of $R$, I think the outcome won't be $\{n\cdot1:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Since $\{2n\cdot1:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is also a subring of $R$. This is a contradiction. I want to know where I was wrong

Comment: Is $2\mathbb{Z}$ considered a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$? It does not contain the identity of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Lozenges It will make sense if we ask the subring of R should contain the identity of R. But I remenber the definition of subring don't require that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definition of “prime subring” is inconsistent with the definition of subring that does not require shared unity.

It could simply be a mistake, yes, or maybe there is more to the context than you are letting on. From scanning a copy it seems there are [some small mistakes](https://wordpress.nmsu.edu/pamorand/files/2018/10/Errata.pdf) in the book of this sort.

I can’t actually locate an explicit definition of “subring” in the book... did you?  If not, I would not get hung up on this and I would advise using the stronger definition.

By the way, the author *does* explicitly say all rings in the book should have identity, and that would make subring a necessarily have identity, eliminating one of your examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I find the author's assumption about ring in the appendix.